# Integer valued solution to equation $x^2+y^2+1=xyz$

Tags: number-theory

The question goes like this: For $x,y,z\in\mathbb{N}$, $x^2+y^2+1=xyz$.

Prove $z = 3$.

How do I even start?

Comment: Very close to (https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~wwu/cgi-bin/yabb/YaBB.cgi?board=riddles_medium;action=display;num=1214032409)

Comment: Looking at the equation modulo $3$ shows that $z$ is divisible by $3$, which is a start.

Comment: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1048219